# how to return unique ownership in c++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I cannot move a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<..>>` from a function:
MSVC complains (C2280) about attempting to reference a deleted function.

How would this work?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
   int i;
};

vector<unique_ptr<foo>> test() {
   vector<unique_ptr<foo>> ret{};

   auto f = make_unique<foo>();
   f->i = 1;
   ret.push_back(move(f));

   return move(ret);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   auto t = test();
   for (auto j : t) {
// fails here: --^
      cout << j->i << endl;
   }

   getchar();
}
```

The complete error message reads:

> 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: The error message points to the foreach loop.

Comment: sorry, on my way

Comment: `return move(ret);` just `return ret;` is enough.

Comment: You do know how a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is working? What you're attempting to do is *copying* the values from the vector.

Comment: I tried to move(ret) because I thought that the copying might happen there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude nope - my c++ ain't very strong - back in school there were no smartptrs - I have some catching up to do I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the function, it's the loop...

```
for (auto j : t)
```

... which attempts to copy-initialize `j` for each element of `t` in turn. Recall that a plain `auto` means value semantics. Use a reference instead:

```
for (auto const& j : t)
```

Comment: thank you very much! it looks like I only need a reference thou (it works without the 'const' keyword) - what does the const do that the & doesn't?

Comment: @santa - Prevents you from accidentally modifying the pointer itself. I favor const-correct code by default. Strictly speaking, you don't *have* to use a const reference here, it's just a good rule of thumb.

Comment: thank you - my brain just f**ed up and thought references are non-modifyable pointers - but they were non-nullable pointers - const made them non-modyfiable.

Comment: @santa • it is a const reference to the unique_ptr.  The unique_ptr is, itself, an object.

Comment: @santa they are imutable pointers indeed. The referee is what may or may not be mutable - depending on CV qualifiers in reference declaration.